# GPIO in ARCHLINUX on Cubieboard a10

Tags: gpio

I have installed archlinux on cubieboard A10,
but i didnt find any /sys/class/gpio file in cubieboard.

I want to know, how i will access cubieboard GPIO pin and make LED blink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a noobi I found it difficult to begin with arch Linux. I found cubian+ xfce4 is easy for programming with python + wiring-cb. You can follow this page for more information

https://github.com/cubieplayer/Cubian/wiki/Get-started-with-Cubian

To blink leds in python : http://www.cubieforums.com/index.php?topic=766.0
I am writing a python script to check cubieboard1’s pinpoints/ headers. please feel free to ask if you need it.

edit

Ok, l am sorry about that. I thought he is a beginner like me.  I really searched for answers for long time and could not find a clear one. So I gave an easy way.
So the difficult path to an answer start like this.
Check your script.bin has enabled gpio and your kernel has built in sunxi gpio?

```
[1] In kernel it should be enabled: Kernel with SUN4I_GPIO_UGLY = y 
[2] Use bin2fex tool from sunxi-tools to check your script.bin usually in /boot.

./bin2fex /path/to/script.bin > script.fex 
nano script.fex
```

eg: the last paragraph of script.fex should contain

```
[gpio_para]
gpio_used = 1
gpio_num = 67
gpio_pin_1 = port:PG03<1><default><default><1>
gpio_pin_2 = port:PB19<1><default><default><1>
gpio_pin_3 = port:PB18<1><default><default><1>
~to
gpio_pin_66 = port:PB10<1><default><default><1>
gpio_pin_67 = port:PH07<1><default><default><1>
```

Comment: Actually I have the limitation to use only Archlinux, i installed Archlinux from [link]http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/allwinner/cubieboard .but in this there is NO /sys/class/gpio file present